# Where are the OpenERP XML Schemas published?

Tags: xml, odoo

OpenERP uses XML for configuration & data files among others. They represent the serialization format of some system objects like views, actions, etc.

So, somebody knows where are the corresponding XML schemas or DTDs published for each version ? It would help me to know which nodes and attributes are valid for each code version. Also it could let me have validation and auto-completion in some editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search the server project for `*.rng`, you'll find them in two places. In 5.0, [the `bin/addons/base/rng` folder](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/5.0/files/head:/bin/addons/base/rng/) had a bunch of files to describe view definitions, but they've all been merged into [`view.rng`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/rng/view.rng) for 6.0. The other place is [the `import_xml.rng` file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/import_xml.rng) that describes module data files.

Comment: I was expecting DTD or XSD but RNG seems to be OK.
Thanks !